# Extract entities from spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I have a python file for webscraping : scrapper.py::

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
source = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willis').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

def my_function():

    heading = soup.find('h1',{'id':'firstHeading'}).text
    print(heading)
    print()
for item in soup.select("#mw-content-text"):
        required_data = [p_item.text for p_item in item.select("p")][1:3]
        print('\n'.join(required_data).encode('utf-8'))

    Willis= soup.find("caption",{"class":"fn org"}).text
    print(Willis)
    print()
```

I want to use spacy to extract entities from scrapper.py :: pyspacy.py

```
import spacy
import scrapper

entity_list = []

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")


doc = nlp(scrapper.my_function())

for entity in doc.ents:
    entity_list.append((entity.text, entity.label_))
print(entity_list)
```

It just gives me the output:: in terminal for the scraped data along with error::

```
** 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hakuna_spacy.py", line 12, in <module>
    doc = nlp(printwo.pubb())
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", 
line 423, in __call__
    if len(text) > self.max_length:

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

 **
```

What is that I'm doing wrong? Can someone explain me please?

Answer (score 1):

In your initial code snippet, you had the problem that `pubb` prints text to `stdout` but does not return a value. You would try instead:

```py
def pubb():
    return 'hello, world'
```

[Edit]:

In the edited version, there are some other issues I can see.

The fetch works, so:

```py
>>> source = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willis').text
>>> len(source)
36836
```

bs4 correctly finds the heading too:

```py
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
>>> soup.find('h1',{'id':'firstHeading'}).text
'Willis'
```

bs4 also finds an item in the content section (just 1):

```py
>>> len(soup.select("#mw-content-text"))
1
```

The trouble then is that it doesn't find any content per se:

```py
>>> soup.select("#mw-content-text")[0].select("p")[1:3]
[]
```

And it doesn't find the caption:

```
>>> soup.find("caption",{"class":"fn org"})                                                                                                                                                                   
>>>
```

You also have the pre-existing issue that you are not returning any text from `my_function`, so the wrapper that passes the return value of that function into the `spacy` call is passed `None` which gives you the exception. **What do you want `my_function` to return?**

Comment: I got the idea for basic code on how to run it. But I cannot implement for the actual program where I want to implement it. Can you please take a look at the program Scrapper.py and suggest me the changes? I have made the edit with the actual program.

Comment: Yep, still the main problem as far as I can see at this point is the same as before. The function `my_function` should return a string, but you call `print` at the end so it returns `None`.

Comment: So yeah I followed your instruction to return instead of print. But it prints only 
    heading = soup.find('h1',{'id':'firstHeading'}).text
        return(heading)
        print()
But doesnot give output of rest of the program. I changed all print statement to return.